# In Octobercms, Can someone tell me how to get a CMS page parsed content?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

Can someone tell me how to get a CMS page parsed content ( html content without any **{% component code %}** or **{% partial code %}** ) in a Plugin boot method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I find out.

There is an event `cms.page.render`  where I can access page content.

```
Event::listen('cms.page.render', function (\Cms\Classes\Controller $controller,
$pageContents) {
});
```

Here **$pageContents** has what I needed.